# Reading text file in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, file

My code-

```
$filename = basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
$ext = substr($filename, strrpos($filename, '.') + 1);
if (($ext=="txt")
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 2000000))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
  else
    {$newname = 'news/'.$filename;
     move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$newname);
     $fileread = $newname;
    //reading a file
$file = fopen($fileread, "r") or exit("Unable to open file!");
//Output a line of the file until the end is reached
while(!feof($file))
  {
      //inserting each data into table
      $insert = "insert into $name (serial,data,used) values('','fgets($file)','0')";
      $query = mysqli_query($connect,$insert);
      if($query)
      {
          echo "cool";
      }
  }
```

So user uploads text file which contains data per line. I want to insert the data into the database till the query is executed.

What is getting inserted into db is fgets(Resource id #6) -  and this keeps on going till i stop.,..it is uncontrolled...

Comment: There is a security risk.  From what I am seeing, it's grabbing all of the text files in a specific folder and reading them.  Any text files could have any contents.  Mysql injection can occur, which Marc B explains.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to store the file's contents in the database? Just store the file name of the (presumably) uploaded file... o_O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  $insert = "insert into $name (serial,data,used) values('','fgets($file)','0')";
```

You're inserting the literal text `fgets($file)` into your database, because it's embedded in the parent string. You'd want something like this, instead, which also (incidentally) removes sql injection vulnerabilities:

```
 $string = fgets($file);
 $string = mysql_real_escape_string($string);
 $insert = "insert into ... values ( ..., '$string', ...)";
```

Why escape it? I don't know what's in that text file, but if ANY of the text contains so much as a single quote, it'll cause that particular insert to fail with an SQL syntax error, and now you've got a missing line in the database.

Comment: whoa...u totally rock..it worked flawlessly...thanks again to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the fgets call out of single quotes which make it a string.

Answer (score 0):

The function cannot be identified in the string and so is interpreted as raw text.

I'd recommend:

```
//inserting each data into table
$data = fgets($file);
$insert = "insert into $name (serial,data,used) values('', {$data}, '0')";
```